# error while returning data from firebase in xamarin app

Tags: c#, firebase, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a c# appliction which is deal with firebase data base on order to get data from it for specific item, `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property` return this error in `AppintmentService.GetFollowUp(patient.ID)` line,
what is the mistake i did ?

```
public ICommand Appearing { get => _Appearing; set => SetProperty(ref _Appearing, value, nameof(Appearing)); }

 public PatientProfileFollowUpPageModelView(Patient patient)
        {
            Appearing = new AsyncCommand(async () => await LoadData(patient));
        }
```

The function :

```
async Task LoadData(Patient patient)
        {
            Appoitments = new ObservableCollection<Appoitment>(await AppintmentService.GetFollowUp(patient.ID));

        }
```

and the service :

```
public ObservableCollection<Appoitment> GetFollowUp(string PatientID)
        {
            var FollowUp = firebaseClient
             .Child($"Specalists/{PreferencesConfig.Id}/Patients/{PatientID}/Appointments")
             .AsObservable<Appoitment>()
             .AsObservableCollection();

            return FollowUp;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetFollowUp` is a method on the class `AppintmentService`, so you need an **instance** of `AppintmentService` in order to call it.

```
var svc = new AppintmentService);
var result = svc.GetFollowUp(patient.ID)
```

alternately, you can make `GetFollowUp` a **static** method, which would allow you to call it without having an instance

in either case, `GetFollowUp` is **not marked async**, so calling it using `await` is not neccessary